# retrieving a row using laravel eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get back single row where a user just added a new car. I am trying to join all tables using the eloquent ORM. here is a erd of my database [image] I am new to laravel, and I would want to know how I would be able to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried already?

Assuming you want to get latest added Car model, you could do

`$latestCar = Car::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();`

If you have nothing yet, you could watch [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com) about how to build a database and set up Models.